# Regex to replace hyphen in middle of a word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How can I replace a hyphens in the middle of a word using python3 and re.sub()?

"-ice-cream- - hang-out" -> "-ice cream- - hang out"

Thanks,

Barry

EDIT: I tried

```
self.lines = re.sub(r'\w(-)\w', " ", self.lines)
```

but wasn't sure how to proceed. I like the /b way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])` see [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Your pattern would be `r'\b-\b'`

See the pattern [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ui01)

And replace this with a space  (`' '`)

The `r` before the regex string deifnes a raw string, that means you don't need double escaping.

`\b` is a word boundary, that means it will match on a `-` when there is a word character before and after.

Comment: @agf I am not sure what sub is replacing. But the regex part will match a hyphen surrounded by word characters and not by whitespace. A hyphen is a non word character and whitespace is a non word character, so no word boundary to match.

Comment: @agf: You are very very wrong.  `\b-\b` matches a single HYPHEN-MINUS surrounded by “word” characters at either side.  **You are utterly confused about what `\b` does!** A `\b` is exactly the same as `(?:(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w))`.  Please read that very closely until you understand what it is doing!

Comment: Yeah, that was wrong, I was thinking `_`, so letters on either side wouldn't be a word boundary, my bad.

Comment: Yes this works thanks! <pre>self.lines = re.sub(r'\b-\b', " ", self.lines)</pre> I wasn't sure how to match on non whitespace without replacing them also.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)-(\w)', lambda m: '%s %s' % (m.groups()), '-ice-cream- hang-out')
'-ice cream- hang out'
```

Comment: There is no need to match word chars.  The `\b` assertion suffices.  Remember that it means `(?:(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w))`.